# What is this pipe in my basement?

Tags: water, basement, pipe

I have a lot of water coming into my basement from a line that is next to where my water pump feeds into. It has been raining a lot lately. I found a pipe in the basement that looks like it could be a drain.

I ran a hose from the line and put it into the pipe in the basement. I am thinking that it is a drain of some sort but just worried that it is something else and I should not be running water into it.

Any thoughts?

**EDIT:** Thank you both for responding. The water is coming from a pipe in the wall in the basement. There was a bucket under it when we bought the house a couple years ago but never knew why. Yes, that pit is in my basement floor with a pipe. So far the water going in is draining to somewhere. House was built in 50's.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a dry well. If so, then it is a drain of sorts.